# Java : How to get type of List<?>

Tags: java, generics, reflection, wildcard

I'm working on reflection in java.
I know this is a common question and there are a lot of articles about it but I'm a bit confused and can't seem to find the right solution for what I'm trying to achieve.

I have :

```
public class ClassA {
    private List<?> myList;
    // getters, setters
}
```

"myList" will contain a list of objects (DTOs) :

```
List<?> myList; // could be List<DTO1> or List<DTO2> ...
```

I'm trying to get the type of the list from another class like this :

```
public class ClassB {
    public void myMethod() {
        // get type of ClassA.getMyList()
    }
}
```

I can only get "ArrayList" when I try using stuff like getClass(), getType()...
Trying to get the class of an element in the list results in "LinkedHashMap".

I really want to achieve this by using a wildcard type for the list.

So is there a way I can get the type of myList with minimal code ?

---

EDIT :

Thank you all for your answers.

Just one thing : `myList` contains elements of type `LinkedHashMap`, this wasn't very clear on my post.

It seems this really can't be done. Each `LinkedHashMap` represents an object but you can't know which one. They are just a list of keys + values.

Comment: did you try `ClassA.getMyList().get(0).getClass()` ??

Comment: You can't. Type erasure. `ClassA` should probably be generic. `class ClassA<T> { private List<T> myList; }`

Comment: @Michael but if you do a `getClass()` from any element in the `List` you will get it, won't you?

Comment: @Paplusc What if it's a `List<Object>`? The first element could be a string, the second could be an integer, the third could be a HashMap. Getting the class of the first element doesn't tell you much.

Comment: @Michal True that, i didn't think in that possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. I dont know it will solve your purpose or not but may be help.

```
 import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       ClassA classA = new ClassA();

       List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();

       strs.add("A");
       strs.add("B");

       classA.setRepos(strs);

        String typeOfList = classA.getRepos().getClass().getTypeName();
        System.out.println("Type of variable in classA : "+typeOfList);

        String typeOfListData = classA.getRepos().get(0).getClass().getTypeName();
        System.out.println("Type of data inside the list : "+typeOfListData);

       for (String s: (List<String>)classA.getRepos())
       {
           System.out.println(s);
       }
    }

}
```

ClassA will be like this

```
import java.util.List;

public class ClassA {
    private List<?> repos;

    public List<?> getRepos() {
        return repos;
    }

    public void setRepos(List<?> repos) {
        this.repos = repos;
    }
}
```

Output will be like this :

```
Type of variable in classA : java.util.ArrayList
Type of data inside the list : java.lang.String
A
B
```

Answer (score 0):

> Duplicates:
>   [Get generic type of class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime)

That example demonstrates that any list can hold objects of any classes:

```
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    List list = stringList;
    list.add(new Object());
    for (String s : stringList) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Only thing that you can do - is to test classes of elements if the list contains any.